# Apache Directory with Authentication

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication

Here is my virtualhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/user1/htdocs/folder1
    ServerName folder1.hostname.tld
    <Directory /home/user1/htdocs/folder1>
            AuthType Digest
            AuthName "private"
            AuthUserFile /home/user1/passwd
            Require user superman
            #Order allow,deny
            #Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've added the user with :

```
htdigest -c /home/user1/passwd private superman
```

Apache keep giving me in its log :

```
client denied by server configuration: /home/user1/htdocs/folder1/
```

I don't know what's wrong... Apache has the right to read the passwd file. In addition if I comment the AuthDigest... lines and uncomment the Order and Allow, apache serves the folder like a charm. Apache responds me with a 403 and doesn't prompt my browser for user/pass ..

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `Satisfy` configuration directive of Apache.

By default, it is set to `all` (instead of `any`), which means that *both* the `Allow` and the `Require` directives have to be satisfied. By commenting out the `Allow`, you deny access to everyone no matter what the authentication says.

Enabling back the `Allow` will not bypass the authentication for known hosts, and will do what you want. Alternatively, you can also set `Satisfy any`, and leave the `Allow from all` commented out. You can then use the `Allow` to specify hosts that can bypass authentication.

Answer (score 1):

On my CentOS server I was able to replicate your problem when I moved the password protected folder to a user directory.  If the protected folder was located in the default location (as a subfolder inside of /var/www/html) there were no problems.  But if the password protected folder is located inside a user's home directory, Apache errors out.

If you are running a Red Hat derivative of Linux (for example Red Hat Enterprise Linux, CentOS, or Fedora Core), it looks like SELinux is a possible cause of the problem.  To test this, run the following command to temporarily disable SELinux:

```
echo 0 > /selinux/enforce
```

Then try to access the webpage.  For me, that resolved the problem and Apache was able to correctly prompt me the username and password and then access the website.  To then go and modify SELinux you can use the [chcon](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chcon) command to change SELinux security context of a file or a directory.

```
chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_content_t /home/user1/
```

For more information and details on how to use chcon to make this change, check out the section labeled "5.1 Relabeling Files" at the [CentOS Wiki](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux).